# Align use element inside the svg element

Tags: html, css, svg, inline-svg

I am trying to align `use` element inside `svg` element, to extreme left. I tried `text-align: left` and `text-anchor: start` but still the use element is in middle of the svg element.

```
<div class="guy">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#guy"></use></svg>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/Lpoaxa?editors=110)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid" e.g.

```
<div style="display: none"><svg id="guy" viewBox="0 0 123.6 205.2" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
```

or as a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQBmZj?editors=110)

Comment: Thanks. this worked. But I have many svgs in my project. and changing to every icon like this is time taking process. Is there any other way of applying this? (_like through css property? I tried this, which isn't working_)

Comment: No, it's not a CSS property it's an attribute.

Comment: SVG is pretty much completely case sensitive everywhere.

Comment: @Mr_Green javascript can do it

Comment: XSLT transform all your files perhaps?

Comment: @Kaiido nah why would I pre compile those changes? looks unnecessary to me.